# .Include expression inconsistency EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have the following custom method created for Finding entities in our EF context. It can accept include expressions, which seem to work quite inconsistently. For example, specifying an include, creating a query and then creating a list on that query will not include (sometimes) the entity in the list.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions) where T : class
{
  var query = Current.Set<T>().Where(expression);
  foreach (var include in includeExpressions)
  {
    query = query.Include(include);
  }

  return query;
}
```

Any suggestions on why could this happen?

Comment: Just out of interest: Is this a shortened version? Or what is the benefit of this method?

Comment: There can be many reasons why Includes don't work. Please show a comprhensive example of a non-working `Include`.